# Possible to identify in setup which JUnit test case is being executed?

Tags: android, junit

I have writing an Android JUnit test for an activity in my application. The Activity is modal, and can be configured via the launching intent.

I would like to write test methods to test the different modes. This would involve a setActivityIntent call in the setup method, configuring the Activity based on the test case we are running.

My question is, how can I determine which test case is about to be run from the setup method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer to this question is very easy. junit.framework.TestCase has a getName method that returns the name of the current test case. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In Junit 4.X, you can do the samething with TestName class:

```
public class MyTest {

  @Rule public TestName name = new TestName();

  @Before
  public void before() {
    System.out.println("running...", name.getMethodName());
  }
}
```